Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code in Vscode but works fine in Xcode
I am making a flutter app for i-pad, when I try to run it in my vscode it shows the following error:
Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPad Pro 13-inch (M4).

but when I run it in my Xcode, it runs perfectly fine, I have done everything, but still it shows following error. What should I do?

My solution was to move the project directory to a folder that isn’t synced with iCloud. Give it a try! :)
